# Why does minecraft 1.10.2 crash when i join ANY server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 307]
[13:27:36] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Nokturnl
[13:27:38] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: lastServer:
[13:27:38] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[13:27:40] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[13:27:41] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[13:27:41] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[13:27:41] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
AL lib: (EE) MMDevApiOpenPlayback: Device init failed: 0x80004005
[13:27:41] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[13:27:41] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[13:27:42] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[13:27:59] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to play.potterworldmc.com, 25565
[13:28:01] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] [Potterworld] You have 0 friends online
[13:28:01] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] [Potterworld] You have 0 pending friends requests
[13:28:02] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]                                      
[13:28:02] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] You have been healed.
[13:28:04] [Netty Client IO #6/WARN]: File C:\Users\Nokturnl\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\server-resource-packs\5d8921e3ef610235f4d8112ce91b86e16b53db5f had wrong hash (expected A5551EF9BA7C16A38B3946BC012551702CD53866, found 40dab10fb06dbeb3d5767c064054380197f3722e).
[13:28:04] [Netty Client IO #6/WARN]: Deleting file C:\Users\Nokturnl\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\server-resource-packs\5d8921e3ef610235f4d8112ce91b86e16b53db5f
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000019dab6b5, pid=1816, tid=6712
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0x6b6b5]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Nokturnl\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid1816.log
Compiled method (c1)   30225 5608       3       bwn::a (11 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00000000029844d0,0x0000000002985510] = 4160
 relocation     [0x00000000029845f0,0x00000000029846d0] = 224
 main code      [0x00000000029846e0,0x0000000002984ea0] = 1984
 stub code      [0x0000000002984ea0,0x0000000002984f98] = 248
 oops           [0x0000000002984f98,0x0000000002984fa0] = 8
 metadata       [0x0000000002984fa0,0x0000000002984fe0] = 64
 scopes data    [0x0000000002984fe0,0x0000000002985398] = 952
 scopes pcs     [0x0000000002985398,0x00000000029854e8] = 336
 dependencies   [0x00000000029854e8,0x00000000029854f0] = 8
 nul chk table  [0x00000000029854f0,0x0000000002985510] = 32
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather common problem, it has to do with a [Broken Intel Graphics Chip driver](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-32606). Some people find the solution by simply increasing the amount of dedicated RAM to minecraft in the launcher (see the top of the page previously linked). If that does not fix it I'd recommend updating your display drivers to the latest version.